# for comprehension on Lists/Sets in scala

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

This is possibly a naive question. I have a case class 'Book', defined below:

```
case class Book(title : String, authors : List[String])
```

In my main method, I define a few Book records as follows:

```
val books = List(
  Book(title = "Book1", authors = List("Author1", "Author2")),
  Book(title = "Book2", authors = List("Author3", "Author4")),
  Book(title = "Book3", authors = List("Author2", "Author5")),
  Book(title = "Book4", authors = List("Author6", "Author3")),
  Book(title = "Book5", authors = List("Author7", "Author8")),
  Book(title = "Book6", authors = List("Author5", "Author9"))
)
```

I am writing a query to retrieve the names of authors who have authored more than one book, and my query is as below:

```
val authorsWithMoreThanTwoBooks =
      (for {

        b1 <- books
        b2 <- books
        if b1.title != b2.title
        a1 <- b1.authors
        a2 <- b2.authors
        if a1 == a2
      } yield a1)

println(authorsWithMoreThanTwoBooks)
```

This prints `List(Author2, Author3, Author2, Author5, Author3, Author5)` (the name of the authors appearing twice which is quite expected, since every pair of books will be taken twice, like (b1,b2) and (b2,b1)).

Of course I could use `distinct` to solve this problem , but another way is to create the records not in a List but in a **Set** :

```
val books = Set(
  Book(title = "Book1", authors = List("Author1", "Author2")),
  Book(title = "Book2", authors = List("Author3", "Author4")),
  Book(title = "Book3", authors = List("Author2", "Author5")),
  Book(title = "Book4", authors = List("Author6", "Author3")),
  Book(title = "Book5", authors = List("Author7", "Author8")),
  Book(title = "Book6", authors = List("Author5", "Author9"))
)
```

Output after `for` expression and `println`: `Set(Author5, Author2, Author3)`

Why does this behavior happen? Why does the `for` expression on `Set` generate another `Set` and not a `List`? Is it possible to get a `List` of the relevant authors with the duplicate values if ever required?

Comment: How set can contain duplicates?

Comment: They can't, that's what I meant to say there. Did I miss anything?

Comment: My question is that why are we getting a Set from the for expression on the latter definition of 'books', and not a List. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? If you feel I haven't really answered your question, feel free to explain what's still puzzling you.

Comment: I did manage to solve it, had lost track of the question, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, `for` expressions are actually translated by the compiler into combinations of higher order functions:

- using a `for` that yields something is translated into combinations of **map**, **flatMap**, and **withFilter**
- using a `for` that doesn't yield anything is translated into **withFilter** and **foreach**

If you are unfamiliar with this, perhaps you should look it up somewhere ([here's](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html) one option).

So, your construct

```
for {
  b1 <- books
  b2 <- books 
  if b1.title != b2.title
  a1 <- b1.authors
  a2 <- b2.authors 
  if a1 == a2
} yield a1
```

is translated into

```
books.flatMap(b1 => books
  .filter(b2 => b1.title != b2.title)
  .flatMap(b2 => b1.authors
  .flatMap(a1 => b2.authors
  .filter(a2 => a1 == a2)
  .map(a2 => a1))))
```

Flatmapping two `Sets` generates a `Set`. Flatmapping `Set` of `Lists` also generates a `Set`. There is actually much more to this than it seems (it goes back to category theory since `Set` is a monad in this case and `flatMap` is one of its natural transformations, but that's just a digression).

Anyway, I'm not sure what you mean by your last question, but if you want to keep the original `books` collection as a `Set` and get the duplicates using a `for` expression, you can simply invoke `.toList` on the books before operating on them. This way the whole for expression with work on a `List` instead of a `Set`.

P.S.

This shows that the nature of for expressions is much closer to functional programming constructs such as monads and functors (which are manipulated using flatMap and map respectively) than it is to a classical for loop. Unlike classical for loops which are a typical imperative programming construct, for expressions in Scala are completely functional constructs since they are a chain of higher-order functions `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` and `foreach`. Note that this means that you can use for expressions with not just collections, but anything that supports those functions (e.g. you can use them with `Option` or `Future`). It's not a naive question at all and if you were unaware of this so far, it's important to know this. Of course, you don't need to be able to transform any given for expression into chains of maps and flatMaps in the middle of the night, but you should be aware of the fact that it uses those functions "under the hood".